# Getting permission to read facebook user notifications

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

my question is quite simple: does anybody know what permission a facebook application needs from a user in order to be able to read his/her notifications. To read her/his newsfeed for example, you need 'read_stream', but there doesn't seem to be anything about notifications on facebook offical list of permissions: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

At the moment you need to use the Old REST API:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/notifications.get/

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/notifications.getList/

You may also want to look at Requests:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/channels/#requests

Comment: For the REST API call, at this time, you do not need any permissions. You just need an access token.

Answer (score 0):

manage_notifications

This permision enables your app to read notifications and mark them as read.
For more information visit https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/